# WriteOutputValue in C++

Tags: c++

The below works to write string data but I need double
and float data to write.

How would I do this?

```
  bool WriteOutputValue( tstring strValue)
  {


    FILE* pOutputFile = NULL;   
    // Open file
    //_tfopen_s(&pOutputFile, _T("Subtract.txt"), _T("w, ccs=UNICODE") ); 
    _tfopen_s(&pOutputFile, _T("GetBalanceTimeReport.txt"), _T("w") ); 

    if (NULL == pOutputFile)
    {
        printf("error Output file\n");  
        return false;
    }   

    int nRet = _fputts( strValue.c_str(), pOutputFile);
    if (nRet < 0)
    {
        printf("error writing GetBalanceTimeReport\n"); 
        fclose(pOutputFile);
        return false;
    }

    fclose(pOutputFile);

    return true;
 }
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output doubles, ints etc to a filestream, the function you are looking for is fprintf. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/

Example:

fprintf(pOutputFile,"%d %d %f",myint1,myint2,mydouble)